# sympy.Matrix hash value difference

Tags: python, python-2.7, sympy

I am currently using Python 2.7.3, sympy 0.7.1.rc1
I am constructing two matrices like this:

```
import sympy as sp

A = sp.Matrix([[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]])
B = sp.Matrix([[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]])

print A
print B
print A==B
print hash(A)
print hash(B)
```

and the result is...

```
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0]
True
3144597
3144601
```

The hash value of A,B are different. I need to put these two matrix into a set(), but the hash value are different and then I am unable to do what I intended for.
Is it a bug of sympy or I should do it another way?

Comment: 0.7.1.rc1 is outdated. Also, judging by the rc (release candidate), it wasn't expected to be stable. What do you get if you upgrade to 0.7.5?

Comment: Since matrices are mutable, I'm a little surprised they're hashable to begin with.  In trunk, I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'MutableDenseMatrix'`, which makes more sense to me.

Comment: @user2357112 let me try...I was just lazy and use default version in ubuntu

Comment: @DSM OK, I see the problem...I should use ImmutableMatrix...but seems it does not exist in my version...
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ImmutableMatrix', let me upgrade it first...

Comment: Thanks. I think I got it after I switch to ImmutableMatrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the commenters noted, you need to update to a newer version of SymPy. In older versions, mutable matrices were hashable, which was incorrect. Now, `hash(Matrix([[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]]))` raises `TypeError` as it should. If you want a hashable matrix, use `ImmutableMatrix`.